# How to transfer existing WordPress website to new multisite wordpress domain?

Tags: wordpress

**First time Working with WordPress multisite feature.**

I have 2 domain which is a) www.one.com 2) www.two.com

Now I have successfully setup multisite feature in **a) www.one.com** because I want to access the second (www.two.com) site at **www.one.com/two/**

Now can you tell me how can I transfer **www.two.com** to **www.one.com/two/** domain?

What is the best way to do this?

I have the backup of www.two.com domain.

**Your help is highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **Tools Setting** from our Dashboard.

1. Go to **tools>Export** Select all content and Download the export file.you will get .xml file.
2. Go to **tools>Import** and install wordPress importer.than upload the .xml file.

Just refer this link  https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/moving-wordpress-site/.
for step by step Information